# How to open a windows explorer to select a file without hard coding the full location of the file, just the folder using vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to find a way to open a windows explorer window to select a file. I want to open the folder that the file will be in and then select the file manually. It will be a different file everyday so I don't want to hard code the file name just the location. I've found a lot of examples of how to open the file, but none that would allow me to open the folder and then select the file that I want to open. I'm doing this in VBS.

EDIT: Here is the code that I'm working on

```
Option Explicit
dim filename
filename = ChooseFile()
msgBox("File Name is: " & filename)

Function ChooseFile()
Dim ListCameras(20)
Dim objExcel
Dim excelPath
Dim worksheetCount
Dim counter
Dim currentWorkSheet
Dim usedColumnsCount
Dim usedRowsCount
Dim row
Dim column
Dim top
Dim left
Dim Cells
Dim curCol
Dim curRow
Dim word
dim Result
dim x
dim CellValue
REM where is the Excel file located?
dim objFS : set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim objShell : set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
dim strPath : strPath = "I:\DVR\Reports\2014\"
if 1 = Wscript.Arguments.Count then
strPath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
if objFS.FileExists(strPath) then
    strPath = objFS.GetParentFolderName(strPath)
    if objFS.FolderExists(strPath) then
        dim strCmd : strCmd = explorer.exe /e & strPath
        objShell.run strCmd
    else
    WScript.Echo "No", strPath
    end if
end if
end if
excelPath = strPath '"I:\DVR\Reports\2014\" & DatePart("m", Now()) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Now()) & "\DVR Daily " & DatePart("m", Now()) & "-" & DatePart("d",      Now())-1 & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Now()) & ".xls"
WScript.Echo "Reading Data from " & excelPath
REM Create an invisible version of Excel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0  REM don't display any messages about documents needing to   be converted from  old Excel file formats
objExcel.Workbooks.open excelPath, false, true  'REM open (path,  confirmconversions, readonly)
REM How many worksheets are in this Excel documents
workSheetCount = objExcel.Worksheets.Count
For counter = 1 to workSheetCount   'REM Loop through each worksheet
WScript.Echo "Reading data from worksheet " & counter & vbCRLF
Set currentWorkSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter)
usedColumnsCount = currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
usedRowsCount = currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
top = currentWorksheet.UsedRange.Row
left = currentWorksheet.UsedRange.Column
Set Cells = currentWorksheet.Cells  
For row = 1 to (usedRowsCount-1)    'REM Loop through each row in the worksheet 
    For column = 0 to usedColumnsCount-1    'REM Loop through each column in the worksheet          
        curRow = row+top    'REM only look at rows that are in the  "used" range        
        curCol = column+left    'REM only look at columns that are in the "used" range      
        word = Cells(curRow,curCol).Value   'REM get the value/word  that is in the cell 
        select case column
        case 8
            ListCameras(row) = cells(curRow,curCol) 'add the value of the cell to the list of cameras
        end select
    Next
Next
for x = 0 to ubound(ListCameras)
    msgBox(ListCameras(x))
next
Result = msgbox("Sheet " & counter & " is done being read." & vbCrLf & "Continue?",vbYesNo)
if result = vbNo then
    Wscript.quit
else
    for row = 1 to (usedRowsCount-1) 'loop through the rows
        for column = 0 to usedColumnsCount-1 'loop through the columns
            curRow = row+top
            curCol = column+left
            select case column
            case 8  'switching the current camera for the next one in line
            CellValue = cells(curRow,curCol-8).value
                if cells(curRow,curCol - 7).value =  cells(curRow,curCol).value then    'check to see if we've reached the end of the camera list
                cells(curRow,curCol).value = "1"    'start over at the begining
                else
                    if isNumeric(cells(curRow,curCol).value) then   'check if the value in the camera column is a number
                        cells(curRow,curCol).value = cells(curRow,curCol).value + 1
                    else                         'if its not a number, then it's from one of the FBlueIris DVR's and is named differently
                        dim CameraList : CameraList =  ReturnCameraList(Trim(Right(mid(CellValue,1,4),2)))  'gets the list of cameras based on the branch number
                        dim count : count = 0
                        dim match : match = false
                        dim camera
                        for each camera in CameraList    'loop through the camera list
                            if camera =  cells(curRow,curCol).value then    'check if the current camera is in the list (it should be)
                                if count =  UBound(CameraList) then 'check count is equal to the number of cameras in the list
                                    count = 0       'restart the count
                                else
                                    count = count + 1   'add one to move to the next camera in the list
                                end if
                                match = True    'if  the camera in the cell is in the list then this should be true
                                exit for    'exit the loop so that the count does not continue to go up
                            end if
                            count = count + 1   'count goes up so that it will be the next camera in the list
                        next
                        if match = True then
                            cells(curRow,curCol).value = CameraList(count)  'when match is true input the next camera into the cell
                        else
                            cells(curRow,curCol).value = "No camera"    'if not true then enter in "No Camera" so that we will know there is a problem and can find it
                        end if
                    end if
                end if
            end select
        next
    next
    objExcel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "I:\DVR\Reports\2014\" & DatePart("m", Now())  & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Now()) & "\DVR Daily " & DatePart("m", Now()) & "-" &  DatePart("d", Now()) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Now()) & ".xls"
    objExcel.Workbooks("DVR Daily " & DatePart("m", Now()) & "-" &  DatePart("d", Now()) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Now()) & ".xls").Close True
end if
Set currentWorkSheet = Nothing  REM We are done with the current worksheet, release  the memory
Result = msgbox("Sheet " & counter & " is done being saved." & vbCrLf & "Continue?",vbYesNo)
if Result = vbNo then
    Wscript.quit
else 
    exit for
end if
Next
objExcel.Workbooks(1).Close True
objExcel.Quit
Set currentWorkSheet = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing  REM We are done with the Excel object, release it from   memory
End Function

Function ReturnCameraList(branch)
dim tempArray()
Select Case branch
    Case 2 'Branch 2
        redim tempArray(10)
        tempArray(0) = "02lobby"
        tempArray(1) = "02tlr1"
        tempArray(2) = "02tlr2"
        tempArray(3) = "02tlr3"
        tempArray(4) = "02tlr4"
        tempArray(5) = "02tlr5"
        tempArray(6) = "02tlr6"
        tempArray(7) = "02VLT"
        tempArray(8) = "02vltdr"
        tempArray(9) = "02bkdr"
        tempArray(10) = "02atm"
        ReturnCameraList = tempArray
    Case 4 'Branch 4
        redim tempArray(9)
        tempArray(0) = "04lobby"
        tempArray(1) = "04frtdoor"
        tempArray(2) = "04loan"
        tempArray(3) = "04bdoor"
        tempArray(4) = "04vlt"
        tempArray(5) = "04tlr1"
        tempArray(6) = "04tlr2"
        tempArray(7) = "04tlr3"
        tempArray(8) = "04tlr4"
        tempArray(9) = "04atm"
        ReturnCameraList = tempArray
    Case 5 'Branch 5
        redim tempArray(16)
        tempArray(0) = "05_Data_Ctr"
        tempArray(1) = "05_Vlt_Dr"
        tempArray(2) = "05_Tlr_Sup"
        tempArray(3) = "05_Frt_Dr"
        tempArray(4) = "05_ATM_Rm"
        tempArray(5) = "05_Tlr_3-4"
        tempArray(6) = "05_Drv_up"
        tempArray(7) = "05_Tlr_7-8"
        tempArray(8) = "05_Back_Dr"
        tempArray(9) = "05_ATM"
        tempArray(10) = "05_Vlt_Rm"
        tempArray(11) = "05_Tlr_1-2"
        tempArray(12) = "05_Coin_Ctr"
        tempArray(13) = "05_Tlr_5-6"
        tempArray(14) = "05_Frt_Lby"
        tempArray(15) = "05_Emply_Ent"
        tempArray(16) = "05_Frt_Strs"
        tempArray(16) = "Emp_Lot"
        ReturnCameraList = tempArray
    Case 13 'Branch 13
        redim tempArray(9)
        tempArray(0) = "13_atm"
        tempArray(1) = "13_bk_dr"
        tempArray(2) = "13_bk_wall"
        tempArray(3) = "13_drvup"
        tempArray(4) = "13_lby"
        tempArray(5) = "13_tlr_area"
        tempArray(6) = "13_tlr2"
        tempArray(7) = "13_tlr3"
        tempArray(8) = "13_vlt"
        tempArray(9) = "13_atm_rm"
        ReturnCameraList = tempArray
    Case 19 'Branch 19
        redim tempArray(13)
        tempArray(0) = "19outside"
        tempArray(1) = "19drvup1"
        tempArray(2) = "19tlr4"
        tempArray(3) = "19tlr_area"
        tempArray(4) = "19_bk_dr"
        tempArray(5) = "19_tlr_1"
        tempArray(6) = "19_bk_rm"
        tempArray(7) = "19lobby"
        tempArray(8) = "19_tlr_2"
        tempArray(9) = "19_tlr_3"
        tempArray(10) = "19drvup2"
        tempArray(11) = "19atm"
        tempArray(12) = "19_exit"
        tempArray(13) = "19usb"
        ReturnCameraList = tempArray
End Select
End Function
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found a way around this problem. Thanks for the help though @Ekkehard.Horner
I have ended up just doing a search through the files in the folder for the newest file, according to creation date. I attempted to use last modified date, but that more often than not gave me the wrong file. Now the user doesn't get to choose the file manually, but in testing it has not chosen the wrong one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this first google link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/03/17/how-can-i-start-windows-explorer-opened-to-a-specific-folder.aspx):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFS    : Set objFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strPath  : strPath      = "c:\"
If 1 = Wscript.Arguments.Count Then strPath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
If objFS.FileExists(strPath)   Then strPath = objFS.GetParentFolderName(strPath)
If objFS.FolderExists(strPath) Then
   Dim strCmd   : strCmd       = "explorer.exe /e," & strPath
   objShell.Run strCmd
Else
   WScript.Echo "no", strPath
End If
```

Comment: I've added this to my code, but it still does not allow me to choose the file that I want, it just tries to open the folder for reading and fails. I'll add an edit above to show what I have for the code in just a minute.